# How can I update the MobilePhone field with the Data Loader?

Tags: data-loader, fields

I'm trying to run a mass update of a group of leads to include data for mobile phone numbers, but the MobilePhone field seems to be missing as an option in the DataLoader mapping setup.

[image: Dataloader mapping]

(Someone who worked here a long time ago set up a custom field – Mobile__c – for mobile phone numbers, and I'm just trying to copy all that data over to the default MobilePhone field so that it can be properly mapped to the MobilePhone field on the Contact upon conversion).

How can I update the MobilePhone field on Leads???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me.  The standard MobilePhone field was not actually used on the Lead Page Layout.  Once I added it to the Page Layout and restarted the DataLoader, I was able to update it without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check is field level security. It's possible that the creator of the Mobile__c field could have hidden the standard MobilePhone field using Field Level Security: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_fields_fls.htm&language=en_US

Comment: What I want to do is map from the MobilePhone field in my column header to the default MobilePhone field in SF:

![MobilePhone Field](http://i.imgur.com/73LVsOc.png)

I know that the Mobile__c field is unnecessary, that's why I'm trying to migrate the data to the default field, after which I'll get rid of the custom field completely.

The problem is that DataLoader doesn't give me the option to update the default Mobile field.

Comment: Make sure the field is visible via Field Level Security. I suspect that the person who created the Mobile__c field must have hidden the standard MobilePhone from all profiles: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_fields_fls.htm&language=en_US

Comment: I'll add this to my response as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but I'm afraid that's not the issue, since we are on Professional Edition and Field Level Security is only available in Enterprise or higher.

Comment: Ok now I feel silly; I solved the problem by adding the standard MobilePhone field to the Lead page layout.  I guess if it's not being used in the Page Layout, DataLoader doesn't see it?